# TailFile processor not grabbing lines from log

Tags: mysql, logging, apache-nifi

We are having a recurrent issue where our TailFile processor stops looking at the Log file.

The Log file is updated properly, it keeps growing and the processor is not getting the new lines consistently.

The processor has the following configurations:

File to Tail: "Correct File Path".txt

Rolling Filename Pattern: No Value Set (used to be set, but would always grab older files and duplicate the data in the MySQL db).

Initial Start Position: Current Time (again to prevent from duplicating)

State Location: Local

Any ideas?  We keep having to restart, delete the processor, stop re-start it.  Currently, our best option has been to delete the processor and creating a new one.

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? Does the log file rollover at all?

Comment: They do Rollover, everynight at midnight.  The name of the current log never changes though.

We are currently running Nifi 1.0

Comment: There was a bug fixed in 1.1.0 that could be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1959

Comment: So I installed Nifi 1.1.  The processor stalled and now is not ingesting anything anymore.  Simply showing one process ongoing for the past 4 hours

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeComeau..did it worked...we are tried similar , but it does not rolls the file ....